# How to produce true rtl text with CSS

Tags: html, css

Using HTML markup, not CSS, the following code:

```
<bdo dir="rtl">Here is some Hebrew text!</bdo>
```

Produces this `rtl` text:

```
!txet werbeH emos si ereH
```

Using CSS, instead, the following code:

```
<p style="color:red; direction:rtl">Here is some Hebrew text!</p>
```

Produces this non-`rtl` text (but it does right-align it):

```
!Here is some Hebrew text
```

Can I use CSS to achieve the same result I did with HTML markup?

Comment: CSS is not designed for that. What are you trying to accomplish? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The `direction` property is not for reversing text, but for enabling some eastern languages.

Answer (score 3):

You need `direction: rtl;`, `text-align: left;`, and `unicode-bidi: bidi-override;`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/4NtD3/

HTML:

```
<bdo dir="rtl">Here is some Hebrew text!</bdo>
<p>Here is some Hebrew text!</p>
```

CSS:

```
p {
    direction: rtl; 
    text-align: left;
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks to you all; I wasn't trying to do anything but try out HTML and CSS. I was pretty sure that CSS's rtl wasn't meant to be what I call real rtl-I just wanted to know and ThinkStiff showed me how.

Answer (score 0):

Just set,

```
<html dir="rtl">
```

and text and direction will work.